# Dynamic query to immediate execute?

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using the MSDN Dynamic linq to sql package. It allows using strings for queries.

But, the returned type is an `IQueryable` and not an `IQueryable<T>`. I do not have the `ToList()` method.

How can I this immediate execute without manually enumerating over the `IQueryable`?

My goal is to databind to the Selecting event on a linqtosql datasource and that throws a datacontext disposed exception. I can set the query as the Datasource on a gridview though.

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

The dynamic linq to sql is the one from the samples that comes with visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>` is that the second is typed while the first is not. To convert `IQueryable` into `IQueryable<T`> you can use the `Cast<T>()` method.

```
IQueryable myQueryable = ...;
IQueryable<MyType> myTypedQueryable = myQueryable.Cast<myQueryable>();
IList<MyType> myList = myTypedQueryable.ToList();
```

Obviously the contents of `myQyeryable` must be castable into `MyType`. To select the instances of a certain type you can use the `TypeOf<T>()` method before doing the cast.